# Generate a SVG file from bunch of coordinates

Tags: image, svg

I have a text file containing a lot of rectangles defined by their 4 vertex coordinates in x and y. Is there a way I can easily generate a SVG file that draws out all these rectangles so I can open it in a viewer like inkscape or even a browser to look at the arrangement. Ideally if the rectangles can be drawn with 50% transparency so I can see overlaps, that would be really great.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The answer to your question is "Yes". If you want a more specific answer, then you will need to provide some specifics about your environment.  For example, presumably you are looking for CLI script? If so what language do you have in mind?  SVGs are just XML files, so any scripting language that can manipulate text files could generate the SVG quite easily.

Comment: `sed` or `awk` might be an option...

Comment: Scripting is not a problem. I know nothing about writing SVG files. So I was looking to find out what to write in the SVG file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use awk or gawk...

assuming your coordinates file look like this (coords.txt):

```
5,3,20,12
15,8,27,22
8,2,12,8
```

you can use awk to turn it into svg...

(script.awk)

```
BEGIN {print "<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" viewBox=\"0 0 100 100\">"}
  {print "<rect x=\""$1"\" y=\""$2"\" width=\""$3-$1"\" height=\""$4-$2"\" fill=\"rgb("int(rand()*255)","int(rand()*255)","int(rand()*255)")\" opacity=\"0.5\"/>" }
END {print "</svg>"}
```

to invoke the script, run

```
awk -F "," -f script.awk coords.txt > rects.svg
```

the output will look like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <rect x="5" y="3" width="15" height="9" fill="rgb(60,74,215)" opacity="0.5"/>
    <rect x="15" y="8" width="12" height="14" fill="rgb(38,149,49)" opacity="0.5"/>
    <rect x="8" y="2" width="4" height="6" fill="rgb(206,44,123)" opacity="0.5"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: p.s.: i'm just learning awk myself, so this seemed like an oportunity...

Comment: Thank you very much! If I want to orient the rectangle at an angle wrt the horizontal axis how can I represent the rotation in svg?

Comment: It's `<rect ... transform="rotate (45,10,20)" .../>` with rotate(angle, x,y) where angle is the angle of rotation, and x,y is the center of rotation.